# GA4 conversion/purchase tracking using Measurement Protocol results in source/medium "not set"

Tags: google-analytics-api, google-analytics-4, event-tracking, measurement-protocol, conversion-tracking

I'm trying to send purchases to GA4 using the Measurement Protocol API.

Here ist my request:

```
https://www.google-analytics.com/mp/collect?measurement_id=G-xxxxxxxxxx&api_secret=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

array(4) {
  ["client_id"]=>
  string(20) "123456789.1691234567"
  ["non_personalized_ads"]=>
  bool(true)
  ["events"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    array(2) {
      ["name"]=>
      string(8) "purchase"
      ["params"]=>
      array(12) {
        ["currency"]=>
        string(3) "EUR"
        ["transaction_id"]=>
        string(16) "123456"
        ["shipping"]=>
        float(6.9)
        ["tax"]=>
        float(4.81)
        ["value"]=>
        float(30.14)
        ["items"]=>
        array(1) {
          [0]=>
          array(6) {
            ["item_id"]=>
            string(11) "654321"
            ["item_name"]=>
            string(36) "Test-Item"
            ["item_brand"]=>
            string(9) "Test-Brand"
            ["price"]=>
            float(23.24)
            ["quantity"]=>
            float(1)
          }
        }
        ["engagement_time_msec"]=>
        int(1)
        ["session_id"]=>
        string(10) "1697002512"
      }
    }
  }
  ["timestamp_micros"]=>
  int(1697002689740112)
}
```

I'm extracting the client_id from the _ga-cookie and the session_id from the _ ga _[MeasurementId]-cookie like this:

_ga=GA1.1.**123456789.1691234567** => client-id = 123456789.1691234567
_ga_xxxxxxxxxx=GS1.1.**1697002512**.2.1.1697001234.45.0.0 => session_id = 1697002512

Both cookies where initally set with the gtag.js from GA4, the user interacted with the page before.

The conversions show up in GA4, but no matter where the users came from, almost all of the turnover is assigned to source/medium "not set". Therefore, no conversions at all pop up in Google Ads.

Any idea what might be wrong? I sent the requests to /debug/mp/collect, but no problems or validationMessages where shown here. I'm a bit lost now where to continue to debug this stuff.

Comment: if you have created custom dimensions you should wait almost 48 hours. if it has already passed this time, then explain exactly how you have created them and how you are sending the info to these custom dimensions

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm not sending any custom dimensions yet, all the fields I use are from the documentation of the Measurement Protocol.

Comment: how are you assigning the values in the front-end?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. I'm tracking the users via gtag.js (if they agreed), but the purchases should be send to Analytics via the measurement protocoll because sometimes the confirmation of a sale comes when the user already left the site.

Comment: I mean the piece of code which is assigning your desired value to the related parameter. The front-end developer does that usually.

Comment: Which value do you mean in particular?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The session_id must be a number (int).

Comment: Ahhhh... Thanks a lot, this works. It's always the small things.

Answer (score 0):

The issue you're experiencing with "not set" source/medium in Google Analyticts can be resolved by including the Session ID (SID) in your measurement requests. The Session ID is crucial for accurate tracking of source/medium and landing page data in GA4.
your new request should be like this:

```js
curl 'https://www.google-analytics.com/mp/collect?&measurement_id=G-NHG43Z5FVJ&api_secret= ' \
  -H 'authority: www.google-analytics.com' \
  -H 'accept: */*' \
  -H 'accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.9' \
  -H 'content-type: text/plain;charset=UTF-8' \
  -H 'origin: https://ga-dev-tools.google' \
  -H 'referer: https://ga-dev-tools.google/' \
  -H 'sec-ch-ua: "Google Chrome";v="117", "Not;A=Brand";v="8", "Chromium";v="117"' \
  -H 'sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?1' \
  -H 'sec-ch-ua-platform: "Android"' \
  -H 'sec-fetch-dest: empty' \
  -H 'sec-fetch-mode: cors' \
  -H 'sec-fetch-site: cross-site' \
  -H 'user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0; Nexus 5 Build/MRA58N) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/117.0.0.0 Mobile Safari/537.36' \
  --data-raw '{"client_id":"","user_id":"1235467","timestamp_micros":"1696098319000000","non_personalized_ads":false,"events":[{"name":"purchase","params":{"items":[],"currency":"USD","transaction_id":"rte2319","value":1.1,"ga_session_id":1696098149}}],"validationBehavior":"ENFORCE_RECOMMENDATIONS"}' \
  --compressed
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. According to https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/ga4/sending-events?hl=en&client_type=gtag the Session ID-parameter should be named "session_id", which I'm including already. Can you confirm that "ga_session_id" is the correct name for transmitting the session id?

Comment: Maybe both of them work, but I sent this parameter, and it's ok. Also you can check in your big query dataset schema, custom definitions in GA4 ande debug view that the standard name for sid is ga_session-id.